# Can First-Order Horn formulae contain existential quantifiers?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to understand which formulas are encapsulated by first-order Horn logic, with an aim of differentiating it from other logics used for knowledge representation and reasoning (KRR).

My lecture notes give the following formula as an example of a Horn formula:

$$∀x.(JuvDisease(x) → ∃y.(Affects(x, y) ∧ Child(y)))$$

It seems to me that due to the presence of the existential quantifier and conjunction on the RHS of the implication, this should be excluded from first-order Horn logic but perhaps I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I've realised my mistake. The definition of a
Horn Formula is given as a "FOL sentence that in CNF yields [a] Horn clause".

$$
\begin{align*}
&∀.(()→∃.((,)∧ℎ())) \\
&\equiv ∀x.∃y.(JuvDisease(x) → affects(x, y)∧ℎ())
\end{align*}
$$

which, when skolemised, yields

$$
∀x.(JuvDisease(x) → affects(x, f(y))∧ℎ(f())).
$$

In CNF, this is

$$
∀x.((JuvDisease(x) → affects(x, f(y)))∧(JuvDisease(x) → ℎ(f())))
$$

which is the conjunction of two Horn clauses, making it a Horn fomula.